# Button in my Google Maps application is accidentally triggering my save form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide! I have a Ruby on Rails and Google Maps API V3 mapping application where people can use a form to enter a starting address, waypoints, and an ending address. They click Submit, and the form is hidden by jQuery. In its place appears a Google Map with the driving route and directions. On this same view, the user can enter a name for the map.

My next goal is to save the map information to a database. I've already gotten most of the way there, but I've run into a problem. I want to save the name of the map and the starting, ending, and waypoint entries from the form. However, when I wrap the form around the entire page, users who click "Submit" to view their map automatically save their form to the database. This is a problem because they don't have a chance to name or view their map before saving.

How should I structure the form so that the Google Map submit button doesn't save the form but I can still capture information from the start, waypoints, and end?

CODE FOR MY PAGE:

```
    <!-- This is the map route page -->
    <div id="map-route-page">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <form id="createaMap" action="/newsavedmaps" method="post">
    <input id="savemap_name" name="newsavedmapname" size="30" type="text" value="New Map"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="savethismap" value="Save Map">
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- End of map route page -->

    <!-- This is the form page -->
    <div id="map-form-page">
        <div id="startingpoint">
            <b>Start</b>
            <input id="startinput" type="text" name="starthere" size="56" value="500 Main Street, CITY, STATE, ZIP"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="stops">
            <div id="multiselect">
                <select multiple id="select1">
                    <option value="500 Main Street, CITY, STATE, ZIP">Address1</option>
                    <option value="500 Main Street, CITY, STATE, ZIP">Address2</option>
                    <option value="500 Main Street, CITY, STATE, ZIP">Address3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="endingpoint">
            <b>End</b>
            <input id="endinput" type="text" name="endhere" size="56" value="500 Main Street, CITY, STATE, ZIP"></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();" id="showmapview" value="Show Map">
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- End of form page -->

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `submit` button for your google maps function. Because the button is sitting within a `<form>` it's trigger the call to the server. Strip off `type="submit"`.

It's also looks like you're trying to do two forms, the first for submission to the server, the second for google maps function. If that's the case, I'd move the `</form>` tag above the `<!-- End of map route page -->` comment.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin. If I move the form tag up, though, it won't be outside the start, end, and waypoints. When I tried that before, it didn't save the start, end and waypoints. Any ideas?

Comment: Keeping the tag where it is, I took off the type="submit" and the save works correctly! Thanks.